# I am using spring-integration-sftp version 5.5.12. Getting error while creating sftp connection

Tags: sftp, illegalstateexception, spring-integration-sftp

I am using `spring-integration-sftp` version `5.5.12`.

I am using following code to create session factory.

```java
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(myConfig.getHost());
    factory.setPort(myConfig.getPort());
    factory.setUser(myConfig.getUser());
    if (myConfig.getPrivateKey() != null) {
      factory.setPrivateKey(myConfig.getPrivateKey());
      factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(myConfig.getPrivateKeyPassphrase());
    } else {
      factory.setPassword(myConfig.getPassword());
    }
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    factory.setSessionConfig(buildSessionProperties(myConfig));
    factory.setTimeout(5000);
    factory.setChannelConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

I am getting error: `failed to create SFTP connection. IllegalStateException`.
Reason for Illegal state exception is different like input stream closed, read timeout etc.

**Questions**

1. Is it something to do with connection timeout or using shared state flag being true while creating SFTP connection?
2. Will updating sprin-integration-sftp version to 6.x.x where JSch is replaced by APACHE MINA help in this case?

**One of the Error Stacktrace**

Please note that error stacktrance is different like input stream closed or socket read timeout which get's bubbled up as illegalStateException and failure in sftp connection creation.

```java
[SFTP_CONNECTION_FAILED] Error while connecting to the sftp org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.list(RemoteFileTemplate.java:422)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.lambda$executeWithLock$0(DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.executeWithLock(DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.java:74)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.executeWithLock(DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.java:54)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.executeWithLock(DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.java:43)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:447)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:303)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:398)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:294)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I am getting this error quite frequently. I am wondering would upgrading spring-intergration-sftp would help or not.

1. Since 5.x.x to 6.x.x migration has major breaking changes regarding session factory and it replaces JSch to Apache MINA, I am bit sceptical about it.
2. Does any configuration / setting changes would help?

Comment: According to the stacktrace, you're getting a read timeout suggesting that the SSH server which you connected to isn't responding to something. Are you sure you're actually connecting to an SSH server? Can you connect to the server with the command-line ssh utility, using the same host and port?

Comment: hey @Kenster, this is intermittent error. I have pasted one of the stacktrace for example. Overall I get failed to create sftp connection with read timeout or input stream closed etc.